# Have anyone used Alipay to pay for their Airbnb?

Tags: china, payment-cards, shanghai, airbnb

I am currently a foreigner living in China and I am trying to book an AirBnB in Shanghai through Alipay (since the Host only accepts Alipay and Paypal). However, when I try to check out, I keep getting the error message from the AirBnB app: "We could not charge your Alipay account. Please verify your Alipay account and try again." I was wondering whether this is because I don't have a Chinese national ID? But if that is the case then it's strange, since my foreigner friend managed to pay for his AirBnB with the same method successfully.

I have reached out to AirBnB customer support for this matter, and they have yet responded. I am curious if anyone has experienced the same issue before? And does anyone know how I can resolve this or work my way around it somehow (without requesting the Host to accept my payments offline, which would violate AirBnB's policies)? Thank you.

Comment: Why does your host want you to pay using Alipay? You, as a guest, can pay using whatever options available and Airbnb then sends money to the host with the applicable charge deducted.

Comment: @Blaszard I’m not sure, but the payment methods that are available to me are Alipay and Paypal. There’s no option to choose anything else.

Comment: That is strange. I have always used my credit card to book a room in China. According to [this page on Airbnb](https://www.airbnb.com/help/article/126/what-methods-of-payment-does-airbnb-accept?ibbe=1&topic=447), you can use major credit cards, AliPay, WeChat Pay, (and Paypal I think) in China.

Comment: PayPal may be used if you have a credit card acceptable to them, you don’t need a funded account or anything like that.

Comment: @Blaszard Does that necessarily mean that every listing would allow its customers to pay with those methods? Or can the host limit the options somehow?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I have never actually used Paypal to make transactions before. But Paypal charges you an extra fee if you make payments through their platform right?

Comment: Paypal charges the recipient only when you transfer money; it’s up to them whether they try to recover the charge from you. So far in my experience few do (the only examples I have where I was charged was with Chinese companies).

Comment: Do you have Alipay Rapid Pay (快捷支付) enabled? Most applications connect to the Rapid Pay API, and as such can't be used if you don't enable it. I'm not sure if foreign nationals can use it, though, but I suppose if you have a residence permit then you can.

Comment: @xuq01 I’m not sure where I can find that option, could you help me point it out? If you meant the “One-step payment” in settings, then yes, I have it enabled for AirBnB.

Comment: If you can pay by swiping your barcode at shops, then you for sure have it enabled.

Comment: @Tina As far as I know, the host cannot choose the payment method.

Answer (score 2):

You have to be a Chinese citizen, some are also having problems paying if they are not a citizen as seen [here](https://community.withairbnb.com/t5/Help/Add-Alipay-as-a-non-Chinese-citizen/td-p/342220), you will need to contact the host.

Comment: Best to quote the relevant part of the content in the link, in case the link expires/changes